# what is the value of an object and when could it be null?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, instance

I am starting to learn about object's array and I'm having some difficulties.
I found a simple code of the class `Person` and the class `PersonArray` and one of the methods in the PersonArray class is like this (m_Arr is a Person array):

```
public void Add(Person p)
        {
            if (p == null)
                Console.WriteLine("Error, param can't be null");
            if (m_Arr.Length <= m_Counter)
            {
                Array.Resize(ref m_Arr, m_Arr.Length + 10);
            }
            m_Arr[m_Counter++] = p;
        }
```

My question is when can p be `null`? I mean what values can object have so it won't be null? Also, I have another question - the m_Counter variable (which is a counter) is not initialized, but it's working without any problams. Why is it OK?

Comment: *"My question is when can p be null?"* ... simply if the caller code is `Add(null);`. This is not the same for m_Counter, which is of type `int`, which is a **value type**, in opposition to `Person`, which is a **reference** type

Comment: Here's a page that talks about default values of variables. It's a bit confusing because they claim you can't use uninitialized variables, but I assume that means only if they don't have default constructors... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

For p not to be null it must have been instantiated e..g

`var p = new Person();`

You cannot set any values for `p` in order for it not to be `null`, it has to be instantiated before you can set values on it.

As for `m_counter`, I'm guessing that is an integer data type, so it will be 0 by default.

Answer (score 1):

If an object has not be instantiated then it will be NULL. When instantiated it would be an instance of a person so `p = new Person()`. You could also set it back to NULL like `p = null;`

Answer (score 1):

m_Counter is a native type which will have it's default value.
For integer it will be zero

p can be null
to not to be null you should initialized it like

```
Person p = new Person();
```

before calling Add method

Comment: m_Counter will have 0 if you write m_Counter = default(int)

Answer (score 1):

Every variable is initialized with a default value when you declare it (§5.2 in the C# specs.), since m_counter is an int, its default value is 0 (§4.1.2).
The compiler doesn't complain because m_counter is considered to be definitely assigned as soon as a new instance is created (§5.3.1).

Answer (score 1):

p could be null if you write:

```
Person p = null;
```

the m_Counter seems to be a variable in the scope of the class, so it could be initialized in another part of the code, for example:

```
class SomeClass
{
    static int m_Counter = 0;
    static Person[] m_Arr = new Person[] { };

    public void Add(Person p)
    {
        if (p == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Error, param can't be null");
        if (m_Arr.Length <= m_Counter)
        {
            Array.Resize(ref m_Arr, m_Arr.Length + 10);
        }
        m_Arr[m_Counter++] = p;
    }  
}
```